# Unknown "encore_entry_link_tags" function when using Webpack Encore ^0.21.0

Tags: symfony, npm, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-encore

I would like to use the new version of Webpack encore to have access to all the new features it offers. however after following the steps in the [official guide](https://medium.com/@symfony/encore-0-21-0-webpack-4-support-copy-files-support-webpackencorebundle-987db85fb06d) I can't make it to work and I get `Unknown "encore_entry_link_tags" function`

What I did:

1. Update my php version to match requierement of Webpack encore bundle (>7.1.9)
2. run `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle`
3. update the version of encore on the package.json 0.21.0
4. run `npm install --save-dev`
5. clear cache

I'm not sure why this is not working. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

After digging a bit, I found that I omitted some steps (not mentioned on the guide). Maybe it's obvious for others but in my case it was not.

Here are all the steps in order for it to work:

1. Update my php version to match requierement of Webpack encore bundle (>7.1.9)
2. run `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle`
3. update the version of encore on the package.json 0.21.0
4. run `npm install --save-dev`
5. Add `new \Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\WebpackEncoreBundle()` to your AppKernel.php
6. Add to your config file

   ```
   webpack_encore:
       output_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/build/"
   ```
7. clear cache

I don't know why the Symfony team just assumed everyone would know those 2 steps. Hope it helps

Comment: It is included in the chapter on installing webpack: https://symfony.com/doc/master/frontend/encore/installation.html#installing-encore-in-symfony-applications At least it is included now :)

Comment: the bundle doesnt install itself. we need to add `new \Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\WebpackEncoreBundle()` to AppKernel.

Comment: "I don't know why the Symfony team just assumed everyone would know those 2 steps" I totally agree with this statement. This is the great problem of the Symfony team, it involves too many things, which we do not really know, or are not well explained, and we waste a huge time in solving it

Comment: The author of the question was using a guide posted on medium (see the link in the question). In the official documentation starting from symfony 3.4 it is explained that if you don't use Symfony Flex you have to register the bundle, create webpack config and  some directories manually.

Answer (score 1):

Just run the following 2 cmds:

composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle

composer remove symfony/webpack-encore-pack

This fixed the issue for me, apparently they had upgraded webpack encore package with symfony 4;

Here's some reading:

https://symfony.com/blog/encore-0-21-0-webpack-4-support-copy-files-support-webpackencorebundle

Answer (score -8):

I finally got there. I replaced the twig links with the html they are replaced with, seems to work so far.

Replace...

```
{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}

{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
```

...with...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/app.css">
```

and

```
<script src="/build/runtime.js"></script>

<script src="/build/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: that is basically replacing the functions with hardcoded html...

Comment: I use Symfony 5: It works for me! I wouldn't rule it out so lightly

Comment: pls dont work against webencore. try to use yarn encore dev instead - to build the app