# input file for Webpack Encore

Tags: webpack, symfony-3.4

I'm on Symfony 3.4
I want to use Webpack Encore

I Have followed these instructions:
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/frontend/encore/simple-example.html

I had to follow these steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/53231113/4277724

I must be clause but now in my generated html I have:

```
<link href="/build/app.css?2" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Whereas it must be something like:

```
<link href="/my-app/web/app_dev.php/build/app.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just add that in my `webpack.json`

```
.setPublicPath('/my-app/web/build')
```