# Symfony4.2 Assets compilation

Tags: symfony, assets, symfony4, webpack-encore

I have an app that use Symfony4.2 but started with 4.0 and then 4.1.

It seems the Assets compilation changed in 4.2, there is now `{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}` or a `entrypoints.json` and `runtime.js`.

Or these 2 last files should be there.

Of course I installed the `webpack-encore-bundle` + the npm/yarn package like this [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html).

But when I compile with `yarn encore dev` or `./node_modules/.bin/encore dev` these files are not in my `build` folder.

So I have Exceptions using `encore_entry_link_tags`:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Could not find the entrypoints file from Webpack: the file "/path/to/.../public/build/entrypoints.json" does not exist.").
```

I use [`fomantic-ui`](https://fomantic-ui.com/) as frontend library and it seems to not working with yarn (`yarn install raise some exceptions`) so maybe all the packages are not installed ?

I tried to to `npm install` instead of `yarn install` but seems there is something missing, I still don't have these `entrypoint.json` and `runtime.js` files.

For information here is my webpackConfig

```
// webpack.config.js
let Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
// the project directory where all compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')

    // the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
    .setPublicPath((!Encore.isProduction()) ? '/rapp/build' : '/build')

    // this is now needed so that your manifest.json keys are still `build/foo.js`
    // i.e. you won't need to change anything in your Symfony app
    .setManifestKeyPrefix('build')

    // will create public/build/main.js and public/build/main.css
    .addEntry('main', './assets/js/main.js')
    //Add entry if other js/css needed. first parameter is the generated filename.
    //require scss file in js. (if you addEntry for scss file only, it will create a js file with same name)
    .addEntry('reader', './assets/js/reader.js')

    //file upload with dropzone
    .addEntry('dropzone', './assets/js/dropzone.js')

    //Admin chapter js
    .addEntry('admin-chapter', './assets/js/chapter.js')

    .addEntry('admin-unfollow', './assets/js/backend/unfollow.js')

    //addStyleEntry : for css file only
    .addStyleEntry('public', './assets/css/public.scss')

    // allow sass/scss files to be processed
    .enableSassLoader()

    // allow legacy applications to use $/jQuery as a global variable
    .autoProvidejQuery()

    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

    // empty the outputPath dir before each build
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()

// create hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning()

    .createSharedEntry('vendor', [
        'jquery',
    ])

    .autoProvideVariables({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    })

    /*.copyFiles({
        from: './assets/img',
        // optional target path, relative to the output dir
        //to: 'images/[path][name].[ext]',

        // if versioning is enabled, add the file hash too
        to: 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]',

        // only copy files matching this pattern
        pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg|webp)$/
    })*/

    .configureFilenames({
        images: '[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]'
    })
;

// export the final configuration
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

In the webpackConfig the `copyFiles` methos raise an exception too : `Error: Encore.copyFiles is not a recognized property or method.`

I don't know if I completely messed up something by upgrading from symfony4.1 and installing the `encore` js and bundle, but it seems the new Symfony Assets is quite broken.

EDIT :

I followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230674/unknown-encore-entry-link-tags-function-when-using-webpack-encore-0-21-0) and I now have an exception, preventing all compilation.

```
"./node_modules/.bin/encore" dev Running webpack ...

D:\PhpStormProjects\bookuto\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:235
                                throw err;
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property `createHash` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\PhpStormProjects\bookuto\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\index.js:26:44)
    at Module._compile (D:\PhpStormProjects\bookuto\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (D:\PhpStormProjects\bookuto\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\PhpStormProjects\bookuto\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\cjs.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (D:\PhpStormProjects\bookuto\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (D:\PhpStormProjects\bookuto\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\PhpStormProjects\bookuto\node_modules\@symfony\webpack-encore\lib\loaders\css-extract.js:12:30)
    at Module._compile (D:\PhpStormProjects\bookuto\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (D:\PhpStormProjects\bookuto\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\PhpStormProjects\bookuto\node_modules\@symfony\webpack-encore\lib\config-generator.js:12:30)
    at Module._compile (D:\PhpStormProjects\bookuto\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
```

`yarn encore dev` does the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown "encore\_entry\_link\_tags" function when using Webpack Encore ^0.21.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230674/unknown-encore-entry-link-tags-function-when-using-webpack-encore-0-21-0)

Comment: Well my issue was not the same, I have the `entry_` twig function, but the compilation don't create the necessary `entrypoint.json` file. I followed the steps listed in your link and I have an exception while compiling webpack encore.
My post is updated with the new Exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix it!

For people having an "old" symfony app, take care to

- update webpack version like this : `"webpack": "^4.28.4"`

A warning is raised when you compile webpackEncore :   `WARNING   Webpack is already provided by Webpack Encore, also adding it to your package.json file may cause issues.`
but, in my case, ig I remove webpack frome my `package.json` it stopped working, completely, saying "webpack is not found" or something similar

- update your `"@symfony/webpack-encore"` to at least `"^0.21.0"`
- If you don't have `symfony-flex`, add these following config files

`assets.yaml`

```
framework:
    assets:
        json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/manifest.json'
```

`webpack_encore.yaml`

```
webpack_encore:
    # The path where Encore is building the assets.
    # This should match Encore.setOutputPath() in webpack.config.js.
    output_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build'
```

And in your `bundles.php`

```
Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\WebpackEncoreBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

- update your `"sass-loader"` to `"^7.0.1"` at least (it's recommended, if you have a lesser version it will raise a werning about certain functions in webpack config file.)

Hope I didn't miss something and that it could help other people.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the help! :D
. . .
Moving on to the next error... :/

Comment: THANK YOU! Couldn't find this anywhere.  For projects without bundles.php, just add it like a normal bundle to AppKernel.php. `new Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\WebpackEncoreBundle()`

Comment: To follow up. Come to find out I also didn't need `webpack` in my package.json when using symfony/webpack-encore ^0.31.0.